# MySQL UNION ALL for ExtJS grid - need unique id column

Tags: php, mysql, extjs

I am using an ExtJS 3.0 grid and generate data from PHP using MySQL. I have setup my `idProperty` of the grid on the `id` column. The problem is that I have 2 tables for incoming invoices and one for outgoing invoices with same columns. I want to make a UNION ALL on these 2 tables and show the result into the ExtJS grid. The problem is that there are some duplicate id's coming out from these tables that causes the ExtJS grid to skip them rows. I know I can do simple UNION to skip duplicates but I need every row in the grid, even if they have the same id. There are actually no distinct data that I can relate to.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not add some prefix to the id-column when `SELECT`ing the data:

```
(SELECT CONCAT('in-', id) AS id, ... FROM in_table)
UNION ALL
(SELECT CONCAT('out-', id) AS id, ... FROM out_table)
```

You'll have to make sure that the field-definition for the `id`-field in your reader configuration has the correct type (`auto` or `string` in this case).

If you need the real `id` afterwards, change the query to select the real `id` as well:

```
(SELECT CONCAT('in-', id) AS gid, id, 'in' AS type ... FROM in_table)
UNION ALL
(SELECT CONCAT('out-', id) AS gid, id, 'out' AS type, ... FROM out_table)
```

Your `idProperty` will be `gid` now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `id` is optional in ExtJS. If you leave it off, the grid will compute its own unique ID for each row.